# Materialize : how to "push" select input outside of the modal?

Tags: css, materialize

There is a modal and a select with a lot of options inside.

When the select is opened, it looks like that :

https://jsfiddle.net/m3kxodng/2/
[image]

I feel that the user experience is bad because there are 2 scroll bars and the mouse scroll apply on the modal not on the select.

It would be better like this :
https://jsfiddle.net/m3kxodng/4/
[image]

I've added this to the css

```
.modal {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

But it causes a no-negligable regression : the modal does not have a good height. It is visible when the modal is opened :
[image]

Is this possible to push out the "select" of the modal, without regression? (And without using javascript)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m3kxodng/11/ is this you are asking for?

Comment: Nope because modal content exceed Modal window. I'd like the modal to extend the height body to show all the content

Comment: Do you want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/m3kxodng/13/

Comment: Nope, if you scroll towards the select input and you click on it, you'll see there are two scroll bars and options do not pop out of the modal.